# How to give .html extension to just one post not all post

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting

WordPress Allows us to make a custom link to the Posts like helloworld.html but, How to give .html extension to just one post not to all posts. It would very helpful if you provide any plugin, code or any way.

Comment: Hi, check this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231448/how-to-add-dot-in-post-slug

Answer (score 0):

got to post

then go on specific post

[image: add your custom link]

click on change link and add your desire link.

i hope this helps you better.

go through

[image: follow this steps]

thanks.

Comment: not working it is redirecting to permalink setting page

Comment: do not clikc button click on link to change the link like hello.html

Comment: I have tried but it is making .html to -html. i need .html