# WordPress Pages that use Domain URL

Tags: permalinks

We create WP pages automatically with the dot in the name. They are domain name pages. So our page gets created with the permalink domain-com but if you type domain.com it will show it as well. I have two questions about this.

1. Does that create duplicate content? Since I can access mydomain.com/domain.com and mydomain.com/domain-com, wouldn't that create dup content?
2. These newly created domain pages show up in the sitemap.xml file as domain-com so the page gets indexed as domain-com but we want the pages to get indexed as domain.com. I know there is a custom permalinks plugin out there but it doesn't change the sitemap.xml entries. Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a theme or plugin that adds canonicals for you? As long as the same one that appears in the sitemap, also appears in the page html itself as the canonical, that should be enough to tell search engines which one to index - and therefore prevent duplicate content. What plugin is generating your sitemap.xml file?

Comment: I'm using the XML Sitemap Generator for WordPress 4.1.0. 

The permalink in the page name is using the dash even though I have domain.com as the page name. So I can access the page url by domain-com and domain.com but ideally I would want the sitemap to use the domain.com as the page name and not the domain-com. 

The whole purpose is to get a better indexing for mydomain.com/domain.com so that people can find it. If using mydomain.com/domain-com is no different then I can just not do all this hoopla. LOL

Comment: Here's your solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231448/how-to-add-dot-in-post-slug

Answer (score 0):

1. To verify that this will not be a SEO problem, check the HTML source code of both pages (with the dot and dash spelling). If they contain `<link rel="canonical" href="http://domain/slug">` tags that aren't different from each other, it will not cause a duplicate content problem, as robots will consider this to be two different spellings of the same page, rather than two separate pages.
2. WordPress slugs do not support dots (.) by default, they are filtered out and replaced with dashes (-) by `sanitize_title_with_dashes()`. You can however employ your own filter instead (such as [this one by Andy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/231952/152975)) or use a plugin that does this for you.